# Error overriding jwt_response_payload_handler to send back serialized user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

**I've added a call to UserSerializer**
This is my Serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=user
        fields="__all__"
```

My Custom Model

```
from django.db import models

class user(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

I have added a custom JWT Handler

```
from login.serializers import UserSerializer


def my_jwt_response_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
   return {
        'token': token,
        'user': UserSerializer(user, context={'request':request}).data
    }
```

And in **settings.py** I have

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'login.utils.my_jwt_response_handler'
}
```

When I try to log in, I get this error?

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `firstname` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'firstname'.
```

**Any help would be appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

Have you migrated your database yet? `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

I also recommend you take a look at this blog post showing how to use a custom user model within Django.

https://wsvincent.com/django-custom-user-model-tutorial/

Comment: Have you solved your issue, and if so, what was your solution?

Comment: No solution yet!